# How to preload a network image when the page is loaded in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, networking, widget

My app has an MVC architecture and I load data from my server when my page is launched. My server gives me a list of image urls, and these urls expire after 1 minute. So I would like to preload these images when launching my app to have a List type variable for example.

If I directly put my url in an Image.network() widget, each time the page needs to rebuild, the url will be called again, except after 1 minute it expires, so it won't work more.

Comment: have you tried to use `cached_network_image` ? : https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image

Comment: Here it's my code to display the image. There is an equivalent with cached_network_image library ?

`CircleAvatar( radius: 20, backgroundImage: myImage.image )`

`myImage` type is `Image`

Comment: I replaced `myImage.image` by `CachedNetworkImageProvider(url)` and that works !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package.

Instead of having `Image.network()` try `CachedNetworkImageProvider()`.